# Bitwise operations with numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Suppose I have two [bitboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitboard) represented using a numpy array:

```py
import numpy

bitboard = numpy.zeros(2, dtype=numpy.int64)
```

Let's say that I want to set the 10th bit of the first bitboard. What's the fastest way to do this?

---

There are two ways that I can think of. Here's the first way:

```py
numpy.bitwise_or(a[0], numpy.left_shift(1, 10), out=a, where=(True, False))
```

Here's the second way:

```py
a[0] |= 1 << 10
```

Which one is faster? Is there any other way to do this? In particular, I'd like to know:

1. When I access `a[0]` does numpy return an `int64` or a Python `long`?
2. If it returns a Python `long` then I'm assuming that both methods are pretty slow because they work on arbitrary-precision numbers. Am I right in assuming that?
3. If so then is there any way to get bitwise operations to work on fixed-precision numbers?

Note that I'm using Python version 3.

Comment: Can you not do your own benchmarks to compare them? Also, you can do `a[0]` and check the return type... these are empirical questions, it seems.

Comment: Doesn't make it off-topic. Empirical questions are within the StackOverflow guidelines.

Comment: In addition, it's a good resource for other people who have the same questions that I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which one is faster? Is there any other way to do this?

The second method is faster.

> When I access `a[0]` does numpy return an `int64` or a Python `long`?

It'll return an `int64`.

> If it returns a Python `long` then I'm assuming that both methods are pretty slow because they work on arbitrary-precision numbers. Am I right in assuming that?

More details in this thread: [Slow bitwise operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679139/slow-bitwise-operations)

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up my answer :)

Comment: "The second method is faster." <-- proof? Also, not seeing an answer to the original question in the link you provided.

Comment: Using timeit, _CPU times: user 34 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 34 µs_ for the first and _CPU times: user 8 µs, sys: 1 µs, total: 9 µs_ for the second method. The question was an open ended and I have attempted to answer some of those.